# Computing similarity of two graphs with partially overlapping sets of nodes

Tags: graphs, edit-distance

Consider two graphs $G_1 = (E_1, V_1) $ and $G_2 = (E_2, V_2)$ with their associated sets of edges $E$ and nodes $V$. I'm familiar with concepts such as edit distance for computing the similarity/distance between these two graphs. I was wondering if there are any metrics for estimating similarity between graphs where they contain only partially overlapping sets of nodes, for example, if $V_1 = (A, B, C) $ and $V_2 = (B, C, D)$.

Comment: You could look into maximum common subgraph and minimum common supergraph. Those are other metrics of comparison that don't necessarily need $V_1 = V_2$.

Comment: You can define a set of allowed edit operations (e.g. add vertex, delete vertex, rename vertex, add edge, delete edge) and then call the length of the shortest sequence of these operations that transforms $G_1$ into $G_2$ the distance, but for the result to be a metric you need to be careful that whenever some sequence exists that transforms $G_1$ into $G_2$, there is an equal-length sequence to do the transformation in the opposite direction.  I think it would suffice here to constrain "delete vertex" to delete only vertices without neighbours.  ...

Comment: ... The above certainly gives a computable metric: the distance always exists, since you can always transform one given graph into another by removing all existing edges, removing all existing vertices, then adding all vertices in the new graph, and all edges in the new graph -- and if we avoid silly never-optimal moves like adding a vertex that is not in $V_1 \cup V_2$ then there are only a finite number of shorter operation sequences to consider to find the minimum. But actually computing it could be *very* slow.

Comment: BTW, if "rename vertex" is an allowed operation then determining whether $d(G_1, G_2) \le |V_1|$ is at least as hard as Graph Isomorphism.